# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The function not entering into if condition, because round is dict and match_round is int, so showing error, how solve this?

my modelviewset

```
 def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    gameevent = self.get_object().gameevent
    match_round = self.get_object().match_round
    print(gameevent)
    print(match_round)
    round = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent, match_round=match_round).values_list("match_round",flat=True).aggregate(Max("match_round"))
    print(round)
    if round == match_round:
        Matchscore.objects.get(match_round=round).delete()
        response = {"result": "successfully removed"}
    else:
        response = {"result": "can't delete this round"}
    return Response(response)
```

Comment: Its hard to tell how to fix it without knowing what line the error is being raised on.

Comment: ok sorry , if condition not working, can you please try to solve the issue?

Comment: Matchscore.objects.get(match_round=round).delete()
error in this line

Comment: while i am printing  round getting   {'match_round__max': 3} in this format
but the match_round is getting in  3 int format

Comment: Does the error go away if you do Matchscore.objects.get(round).delete()  instead? Because its not normal to do keyword arguments on get methods

Comment: so i cant satisfy the condition because one is int another is dict, how can i slove this?

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: thats not working

Comment: Can you share your model? You want to only delete an instance if it's `match_round` is the max with some filter?

Comment: what output do you get if you run 'print(match_round)'? and 'print(round)' because if both don't return an int then the condition will always be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare Django DB objects for identity in the DB, i.e. sharing the same DB row, then test their pk for equality.

```
if a_round.pk == match_round.pk:
```

if by some other metric based on other fields, code this explicitly.

In the question, `round` is not a Django DB object at all, it's a `values_list` based on some filtered objects. So you need to extract some values from the result of that query, and the corresponding values from `match_round`, and compare them. I don't have sufficient insight into the problem to suggest the nature of that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    gameevent = self.get_object().gameevent
    match_round = self.get_object().match_round
    print(gameevent)
    print(match_round)
    round = Matchscore.objects.filter(gameevent=gameevent, match_round=match_round).values_list("match_round",flat=True).aggregate(Max("match_round"))['match_round__max']
    print(round)
    if round == match_round:
        Matchscore.objects.get(match_round=round).delete()
        response = {"result": "successfully removed"}
    else:
        response = {"result": "can't delete this round"}
    return Response(response)
```